# Can we write custom classes in POM in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

```
@FindBy(id = "loginUser") 
private WebElement _username;

@FindBy(id = "loginPass")
private TextBox _password;
```

TestBox class which extends Webelement interface.
I am getting the following error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set
>   com.selenium.element.webelementutil.TextBox field
>   com.selenium.element.webelementutil.SampleLogin._password to
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5

Comment: Can u add the code of TextBox. Is it a class implementing WebElement or interface extending WebElement. The problem you are facing is from the proxyForLocator() method in DefaultFieldDecorator - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/DefaultFieldDecorator.java - The implemented interfaces are not matching

Comment: Your code and error message say "TextBox" but your typed comment says "TestBox Class"  Which is it?  Did you simply make a typo in the code?